# How to escape PHP inside the double quotes of html?

Tags: php, escaping, concatenation

My code is

```
 echo '<textarea name="" class="widefat" style="width:100%; height: 100px;" value="<?php ?>"></textarea>';
```

How can I use php inside the value

Looking forward

Thanks

Comment: _How can I use php inside the value_ **To do what??**

Comment: ___Small Note___ `<textarea>` does not have a `value` attribute

Comment: @RiggsFolly — To execute PHP in `echo`ed content.

Comment: @Quentin Well thats what I assumed, but we all know that assumption is the _Mother of all f'ups_

Comment: When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Comment: @RiggsFolly "To do what??" PHP is Turing complete, so I would assume, to execute any desired PHP code. (This is what it means to "use PHP" in this context.) Perhaps a more constructive question would have been to ask what the OP meant by "use PHP," if that is what you had confusion on??

Comment: @Kröw Well thank you for putting me straight on that. However I would draw your attention to my 3rd comment. I have been here a while now and had been even when this question was asked 5 years ago. To summarise, assumptions around here are dangerous, I have spent hours chasing bugs for others where I made assumptions on the abilities of an OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) mentioned, you're trying to `echo` a `php` tag, which you cannot. To use a variable inside a string, without messing with quotes, I normally use [heredoc](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), i.e.:

```
<?php
$value = 100;
echo <<< EOF
<textarea name="" class="widefat" style="width:100%; height: 100px;" value="{$value}"></textarea>
EOF;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The problem here has nothing to do with the HTML. The problem is because you are trying to `echo` PHP tags.

PHP either outputs everything (by default) or executes PHP (between `<?php` and `?>`). If you explicitly output with `echo` then you bypass the parser's search for `<?php`. You can't nest PHP programs in that way.

Refactor your code instead.

```
?>
<textarea name="" class="widefat" style="width:100%; height: 100px;">
<?php ... ?>
</textarea>
<?php
```

NB: Textarea elements don't have a value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following ways,

```
  echo '<textarea name="" class="widefat" style="width:100%; height: 100px;">'.$value.'</textarea>';
```

Or

```
 <textarea name="" class="widefat" style="width:100%; height: 100px;"><?php echo $value; ?></textarea>
```